# p:editor primefaces tabindex não funciona

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2, xhtml

Em uma view .xhtml uso o p:editor do primefaces

```
<p:editor id="idDescription" tabidex="2" >
 ...
```

Quando é pressionado a tecla tab, depois de estar no campo 1, tabindex="1", não vai para o próximo da sequencia, **nesse caso é idDescription** e sim para o seguinte tabindex="3" que é um inputText, isso acontece nesse componente.

- Primefaces 5.3

Como resolvo isso? tem alguma propriedade a mais para configurar para que ele fucione?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A atributo tabidex não é válido para o p:editor, conforme pode ser visto na documentação: http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf.